# Getting the href value of links using jQuery find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure:

```
...
...
    <div id="related-links">
        <ul>
            <li class="first"><a href="some-link"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link"><a href="some-link"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link"><a href="some-link"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link"><a href="some-link"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link"><a href="some-link"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
...
...
```

How can I get the `href` value of all `li` elements in javascript?

I'm currently trying this, but there may not be five `li` always.

```
var related_links_body = $('div.related-links ul');
var related_links = [];
related_links[0] = related_links_body.find("li.first a").attr("href");
related_links[1] = related_links_body.find("li.first").next().find("a").attr("href");
related_links[2] = related_links_body.find("li.first").next().next().find("a").attr("href");
related_links[3] = related_links_body.find("li.first").next().next().next().find("a").attr("href");
related_links[4] = related_links_body.find("li.first").next().next().next().next().find("a").attr("href");
```

Comment: If there are no other links on the page, then document.links will contain them all

Comment: This is a legitimate question and I also worked out a non-optimized way of doing this. Still, I'm wondering why was this downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just aggregate them using `each()`:

```
var related_links = [];

$('#related-links ul li a').each(function()
{
     related_links.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Glad to see you fixed the id selector unlike your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

First your selector is wrong, you are using a class selector, not an id selector

```
$('div.related-links ul')
```

needs to be

```
$('div#related-links ul')
```

or

```
$('#related-links ul')
```

---

---

You can use [jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to get the hrefs into an array.

```
var related_links_body = $('#related-links ul');
var anchors = related_links_body.find("li a");
var related_links = anchors.map( function() { return this.href; } ).get();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jkz4nat/)